# Unable to getResultList for a certain entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
   int v1;
   int v2;

   @ManyToOne
   Bar bar;
}

Query query = EntityManager.createQuery("select foo from Foo");

query.getResultList()
```

doesn't get executed at all. How do I debug this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query is wrong

Modify that as below :

```
Query query = EntityManager.createQuery("from Foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @TheSureshAtta is valid for the Hibernate API. Since you tagged your question with `JPA`,  the according typesafe JPA query may be important:

```
TypedQuery<Foo> query = EntityManager.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Foo f", Foo.class);
List<Foo> result = query.getResultList();
```